# The derivative of normal derivative $\frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf{n}}$

Tags: calculus, differential-geometry

Suppose we are given a curve $\Phi(s)$, and a function $u$ defined on the curve. I encounter a problem that requires me to express the derivative of normal derivative, i.e.
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s} \left(\frac{\partial u}{\partial \mathbf{n}} \left(\Phi(s)\right) \right)$$

I try to express the normal derivative as $\nabla u \cdot \mathbf{n}$, and get

$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s} \left( \nabla u\left(\Phi(s)\right) \cdot \mathbf{n}\left(\Phi(s)\right) \right)=\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s} \left(\nabla u\left(\Phi(s)\right)\right) \cdot \mathbf{n}\left(\Phi(s)\right) + \nabla u\left(\Phi(s)\right) \cdot \frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s} \left( \mathbf{n}\left(\Phi(s)\right) \right)$$

I can derive the first term as,
$$\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}s} \left(\nabla u\left(\Phi(s)\right)\right)=\nabla^2 u \left(\Phi(s)\right) \cdot \Phi'(s)$$

However, **what troubles me** is the derivative of normal vector $\mathbf{n}$. I'm not sure how to express $\frac{\text{d}\mathbf{n}}{\text{d}s}$ using $\Phi$. Does the expression contain something like curvature $\kappa$, or something else?

Comment: How do you define the gradient here?

$$\boldsymbol\nabla\equiv\left(\dfrac{\partial}{\partial x(s)},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial y(s)},\dfrac{\partial}{\partial z(s)}\right)?$$

Comment: What I mean is $\boldsymbol\Phi(s)=x(s)\mathbf{\hat i}+y(s)\mathbf{\hat j}+z(s)\mathbf{\hat k}$

Comment: The function $u$ needs to be defined on a neighborhood of the curve, not just on the curve. And I assume this is all happening in the plane (or on some Riemannian surface)? Please clarify.

Comment: To be explicit, is $\bf n$ the Frenet principal normal or is it the normal to a curve lying inside a surface?

Comment: I assumed it was Frenet's.

Comment: $\Phi(s)$ is actually the boundary of a bounded domain $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^n$. I'm not sure what Frenet principal normal means. Here the normal derivative is just what appears in the Neumann boundary condition.

Comment: So it is a closed curve.

Comment: You mean the bounded domain is in $\Bbb R^2$?

Comment: Not necessary in $\mathbb{R}^2$, but indeed a bounded domain in $\mathbb{R}^n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you initially have some curve in $\mathbf R^3$, $\mathbf r(t)=x(t)\mathbf{\hat i}+y(t)\mathbf{\hat j}+z(t)\mathbf{\hat k}$, you can always (as long as it is invertible) transform it into $\mathbf \Phi(s)=x(s)\mathbf{\hat i}+y(s)\mathbf{\hat j}+z(s)\mathbf{\hat k}$ using
$$s=\int_0^t||\mathbf{\dot r}(t')||dt'.$$

Assuming you're given the unit vector, $\mathbf n(\mathbf\Phi(s))=(n_x\mathbf{\hat i}+n_y\mathbf{\hat j}+n_z\mathbf{\hat k})(\mathbf\Phi(s))$, and using chain rule, you'd get that
$$\dfrac{\text d}{\text d s}\mathbf n(\mathbf\Phi(s))=\dfrac{\partial\mathbf n}{\partial\mathbf\Phi}\cdot\underbrace{\dfrac{\text d\mathbf \Phi}{\text d s}}_{\mathbf \Phi'(s)}=
\left(
\begin{matrix}
\dfrac{\partial n_x}{\partial x(s)} & \dfrac{\partial n_x}{\partial y(s)} & \dfrac{\partial n_x}{\partial z(s)}\\
\dfrac{\partial n_y}{\partial x(s)} & \dfrac{\partial n_y}{\partial y(s)} & \dfrac{\partial n_y}{\partial z(s)} \\
\dfrac{\partial n_z}{\partial x(s)} & \dfrac{\partial n_z}{\partial y(s)} & \dfrac{\partial n_z}{\partial z(s)} 
\end{matrix}
\right)
\left(
\begin{matrix}
x'(s)\\
\\
y'(s)\\
\\
z'(s)
\end{matrix}
\right)
.$$
The other way is by definition:

The tangent vector to the curve $\mathbf\Phi(s)$ is
$$\boldsymbol{\hat\sigma}=\dfrac{\text d \mathbf\Phi}{\text d s}.$$

Since it is normalized we get
$$\boldsymbol{\hat\sigma}\cdot\boldsymbol{\hat\sigma}=1\Longrightarrow \dfrac{\text d}{\text d s}(\boldsymbol{\hat\sigma}\cdot\boldsymbol{\hat\sigma})=0\Longrightarrow 2\boldsymbol{\hat\sigma}\cdot\dfrac{\text d\boldsymbol{\hat\sigma}}{\text d s}=0\iff \boldsymbol{\hat\sigma}\perp \dfrac{\text d\boldsymbol{\hat\sigma}}{\text d s}.$$

Namely,
$$\mathbf n\propto \dfrac{\text d\boldsymbol{\hat\sigma}}{\text d s}.$$
In fact,
$$\mathbf n= \dfrac{1}{\kappa}\dfrac{\text d\boldsymbol{\hat\sigma}}{\text d s}=\dfrac{1}{\kappa}\dfrac{\text d^2\mathbf\Phi}{\text d s^2}$$
where
$$\kappa=\left\lVert\dfrac{\text d\boldsymbol{\hat\sigma}}{\text d s}\right\rVert=\left\lVert\dfrac{\text d^2\mathbf \Phi}{\text ds^2}\right\rVert$$
is the curvature and it accounts for normalization.

Thus,
$$\dfrac{\text d\mathbf n}{\text d s}=\dfrac{\text d}{\text d s}\left[\dfrac{1}{\kappa}\dfrac{\text d\boldsymbol{\hat\sigma}}{\text d s}\right]=\dfrac{\text d}{\text d s}\left[\dfrac{1}{\kappa}\dfrac{\text d^2\mathbf\Phi}{\text d s^2}\right]=\dfrac{1}{\kappa}\dfrac{\text d^3\mathbf\Phi}{\text d s^3}-\dfrac{1}{\kappa^2}\dfrac{\text d\kappa}{\text d s}\dfrac{\text d^2\mathbf\Phi}{\text d s^2}.$$

Note I treat $\mathbf n$ as a unit vector because the OP uses it in a directional derivative at the beginning, meaning it has to be normalized. I point that out because I use the same notation as OP instead of $\mathbf{\hat n}$ like $\boldsymbol{\hat\sigma}$.

Comment: What in the world does $\partial\mathbf n/\partial\mathbf \Phi$ mean? And how is your other formula correct? Assuming arclength parametrization and $\kappa$ constant? At this point, why not use Frenet?

Comment: I'm really sorry: I was rushing for no reason and made some mistakes. I hope it is now better.

Comment: Maybe we can further simplify to $\dfrac{1}{\kappa} \dfrac{\text d^3\mathbf\Phi}{\text d s^3} \left(1- \dfrac{(\dfrac{\text d^2\mathbf\Phi}{\text d s^2})^2}{\kappa^2}\right)$, by taking derivative w.r.t. the norm?

Comment: If you wish so you can further simplify.